# How to pass variable to update query with linked server which is having xml column

Tags: linked-server

How can we pass an integer variable in `where` clause for the following `update` query?

```
Declare @ID int = 2

UPDATE t SET Name = 'assaaa' FROM Openquery([Servername], 'SELECT Name,convert(nvarchar(MAX), Resume) FROM [DB].[dbo].[RRtest] where Id ='+@ID+'')t
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, this worked for me :

Declare @ID int =2

```
UPDATE s SET Name = 'et' FROM Openquery([Servername], 'SELECT ID,Name,convert(nvarchar(MAX), XMLcolumn1) FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table]')s where id = @ID
```